# Error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: java, android

got an while i am doing my code

My Error is :

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.hurricanedev.muslimpro, PID: 13553 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.hurricanedev.muslimpro/com.hurricanedev.muslimpro.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3849) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4096) at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2441) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8396) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:152) at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:132) at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:7158) at com.hurricanedev.muslimpro.activity.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:377) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95) at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1323) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3830) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4096)  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2441)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8396)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)`

My app is crashing after splash screen.

My app is crashing after splash screen.

Comment: share to your code after u will get solution